# applying rule if ad < bc a/b < c/d

Tags: c++

im doing a small program , there are 2 arrays , their sizes are the same , lets say its 5 ,

```
cin >> W;

for (int Q = 0; Q < W; Q++) 

        cin >> PR[Q] >> CA[Q];
```

so , my arrays are filled now ,

(**numbers are just exampple it doesnot matter i mean their sizes**)

1000 300

750 200

950 852

450 250

471 207

now , to understand it better , lets say that on the right side so it means in CA array there are some numbers , which means minutes , literally , and in PR array these numbers are prices , now i need to find the pair which got the smallest price on one minute , normaly i wanted to divide it , but its slow , so i found a rule 
**if `ad < bc` then `a/b < c/d`**
but i am not able to use it in the loop everything else is done i mean definitions etc , i just cannot do this "core" how would it look like ?

i also created 2 loops but couldnot implement it correctly

```
for (int H = 0; H < W; H++) {
        for (int B = 0; B < W; B++) {

}
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this "rule"? I am not the fastest in maths, but I am pretty sure that this rule just gives you an upper (/lower) limit on the result. Thus you could use it to rule out certain entries, but to be really sure that you got the maximum, you cannot avoid to do the division and compare the results.

Comment: oh, after your edit, my comment becomes kind of obsolete ;) I misread it first

Comment: *"but its slow"*, I don't think division would be the bottleneck of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need two loops to use the straightforward linear search:

```
int best = 0;
for (int i = 1 ; i != W ; i++) {
    if (pr[i]*ca[best] < pr[best]*ca[i]) {
        best = i;
    }
}
```

Note that the loop starts at index 1, not 0, because we do not need to compare the `pr[0], ca[0]` pair with itself.

Comment: @josh31 I encourage you to try it on a piece of paper to see why this works.

Comment: @josh31 What's the difference between "exactly the pair of numbers" and an index of that pair in the array?

Comment: @josh31 You mean like this `cout << ca[best] << " " << pr[best] << endl`?

Comment: @josh31 "So what" what? Do you still not understand the algorithm after trying it out on a piece of paper?

Comment: @josh31 Since you already have the values stored, there is absolutely, positively, no point in storing them again. Once the loop ends, they are at `ca[best]` and `pr[best]`.